# Python-PowerShell-(filter\include) not working as expected

Tags: python, powershell, filter, include

Please help to understand where is my mistake.

For testing I created:

1. **test_INCORRECT_FOLDER** with **1 excel** file that should be never dsplayed
2. **test_folder** with **2 excel files** inside (1.xlsx and 2.xlsx)
3. **sub_folder** inside test_folder with **2 excel files** inside (3.xlsx and 4.xlsx).

Using shell command we can get the content
[No any issues with powershell itself. everything as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNA8U.png)

But when I am trying to use it with Python, it is not working as expected.

Python code. super simple

BTW, during code runnning **test_INCORRECT_FOLDER** will be opened in powershell\terminal session

At first the structure:
[FILE Structure (UPDATED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6qE6.png)

[Python code and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoH5A.png)

As you see, I used the same command from powershell in python.
But I am getting fully different results

In python, powershell scan and filter files in current folder.

Excected result:
Correct filtering of excel files by correct path  **test_folder**

```
# Run powershell

import subprocess
import os


os.system("cls")
#Test 1 -----> Static path in powershell
    
print(f"TEST 1 static path in powershell'\n {'*' * 90} \n RESULT:")
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command","Get-ChildItem  C:\\test_folder -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }"])
    
    
print("-------------------------")
#Test 2 ----> Static path 
test_folder_static = 'C:\\test_folder'
print(f"TEST 2 static path in script \n {'*' * 90} \n RESULT:")
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command","Get-ChildItem $test_folder_static -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }"])
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not screenshots

Comment: post the code so that the problem is easy to follow.  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're trying to reference _Python_ variables as if they were _PowerShell_ variables in your PowerShell code, which cannot work. Use string interpolation to embed the Python variable values, and enclose them in embedded ``\"...\"``

Comment: Guys , excuse me (this is my first post on stackoverflow) and thank you for your help.

Comment: @mklement0 I am tried to do as you advice. 
But unfortunately - no luck

Comment: Guys any additional advice ? 

Thank you

Comment: Issue resolved

'import subprocess

# Python variable containing the path
test_folder = "C:\\test_folder"

# Construct the PowerShell command
powershell_command = f'Get-ChildItem "{test_folder}" -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse | % {{ $_.FullName }}'

# Pass the command to subprocess.run
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", powershell_command])'

Answer (score 0):

In the second system call, string interpolation happens in python not powershell. Take a look at [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/), and change the last line of code to:

```
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", f"Get-ChildItem '{test_folder_static}' -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse | % {$_.FullName }"])
```